# Vba script for deleting all rows containing certain text string giving mismatch error as well as transpose script

Tags: vba, excel

I use the following two macros to cleanse data i receive in one column, the first is to cleanse the data for rows containing certain words that aren't required. The second transposes this column into rows identified by a variable (in this case X). Both theses scripts are now coming up with mismatch error 13's when I run them on a new desktop. If anyone can help with a fix would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

```
Sub deletewordsandblanks()

Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = Last To 1 Step -1
        If (Cells(i, "A").Value) = "Surname" Then

        Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete

    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

and the transpose is done by:

```
Sub transpose()
Dim i As Long, lRow As Long, n As Long, j As Long
lRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
n = 1
j = 1
For i = n To lRow
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = "X" Then
        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(n, 1)).Copy
        Range(Cells(j, 2), Cells(j, i)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
              :=False, transpose:=True
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        n = i + 1
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next i
Columns(1).Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: 1. this is not your problem, but you should ALWAYS denote the parent sheet of ALL range objects.  2.  To your problem, are there errors in the data fields?

Comment: Where does the error occur, does it say?

Comment: The line of the 'If' statement in both

Comment: Can't recreate your errors.  Also, if this is to be used as a utility on multiple worksheets, then denoting the parent sheet would be counter productive.

Comment: I read there is a possibility there's an issue running 64-bit vs. 32-bit microsoft office, but don't see how that'd apply here.

Comment: Do you have errors in the data?

Comment: what is the value of i when it errors - what value is in Cells(i, "A") at that point?

Comment: I too do not see any error in the code, may be the part before and after the code you have mentioned here.. might be leading to issue. FYI, there is no version dependent VBA function i see here (to be best of my knowledge).

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not with the code but the data was not correctly formatted and generating the mismatch. It was due to the conversion from the scanned documents into the column. 
Apologies for the mistake and Thanks for your help guys!